# Using clojure keywords to handle symbols

Tags: clojure, keyword, symbols

I'm relatively new to clojure and I wonder what is a good solution to the following problem.

I have two sets of symbols, say:

v1:

```
q w e r
```

v2:

```
a s d f
```

and they are used to build a third set

A:

```
qa qs qd qf
wa ws wd wf
ea es ed ef
ra rs rd rf
```

with all the elements of A are new symbols, but I have to be able to retrieve the single sign symbol. I want to do various operations on A e.g., build another set of all combinations of the elements of A or test for equality.

I came up with these two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
(def A  {:qa [:q :a] :qs [:q :s] :qd [:q :d] :qf [:q :f]
         :wa [:w :a] :ws [:w :s] :wd [:w :d] :wf [:w :f]
         :ea [:e :a] :es [:e :s] :ed [:e :d] :ef [:e :f]
         :ra [:r :a] :rs [:r :s] :rd [:r :d] :rf [:r :f]})

(defn get-v1 [key] (first (key A)))

(defn get-v2 [key] (last (key A)))

=>(get-v1 :qa)
:q
```

**Solution2:**

```
(def A [:qa :qs :qd :qf
        :wa :ws :wd :wf
        :ea :es :ed :ef
        :ra :rs :rd :rf])

(defn get-v1 [key] (keyword (str (first (name key)))))

(defn get-v2 [key] (keyword (str (last (name key)))))

=>(get-v2 :ws)
:s
```

In fact solution 1 is incomplete, because the order of the elements of A matters too. Therefore the definition of A in solution 2 is needed. But I haven't figured out a smart way to create a sorted-map-by in solution 1.

**Questions:**

**1.**
Are keywords the right way to go?

**2.**
If so, is either one of my solutions a good way to do it or is there a much more convenient way? I tend to solution 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving the values from the keys is the more generic solution. This means you can give it *any* key and it will return the "proper" value for it. That is, you could give `:xy` to your second algorithm and it will try to use it even though it is not contained in `A`. If that's a problem, then you first solution seems better.

As for creating a sorted map for your second solution, I would probably take definition of A and generate a sorted map from it. This reduces the manual duplication while allowing you to provide the data set in a more natural way. (Plus, it's easy to test!)

```
(def A [:qa :qs :qd :qf
        :wa :ws :wd :wf
        :ea :es :ed :ef
        :ra :rs :rd :rf])

(defn assoc-v
  [m k]
  (let [[a b] (seq (name e))]
    (assoc m k [(keyword a) (keyword b)])))

(defn make-a
  [elements]
  (reduce assoc-v (sorted-map) elements))
```